# В чём отличие FixedUpdate и Update в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно нашёл такой метод *FixedUpdate*. В своих проектах использую метод *Update*. В чём отличие метода *FixedUpdate* и обычного *Update*?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/10993/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-fixedupdat.html   ... если не будет лень - переведу...но не сейчас))

Comment: Я не знаком с Unity но в курсе, что Update вызывается для каждого кадра, а FixedUpdate с фиксированной частотой независимо от FPS.

Comment: FixedUpdate вызывается 50 раз за кадр фиксировано, но это значение может колебаться, а Update зависит от частоты кадров, но а вообще я не думаю что кто-то получил бан в гугле

Comment: @Methorn а тогда зачем нужен данный ресурс? :)

Comment: @Methorn только не 50 раз за кадр, а 50 раз в секунду. Вам бы получе гуглить, или просто быть внимательным, потому что чуть выше ссылка, где написано `If the physics timescale is left at its default value (0.02) this gives us 50 physics updates per second`.

Comment: и это при стандартных настройках. Можно сделать нестандартные, на сколько я помню, и тогда будет не 50 а 20 или 100)